# How do I get my code to loop until I press a button (Lego EV3)

Tags: python, robotics, lego-mindstorms, lego-mindstorms-ev3

The question pure and simple. I've tried using while loops, rearranging code, but all that happens is that the program starts when i press the button or does absolutely nothing at all. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from ev3dev2.motor import MoveTank, OUTPUT_B, OUTPUT_C
from ev3dev2.button import Button
from ev3dev2.sound import Sound
from time import sleep
import time

sound = Sound()
btn = Button()
tank_pair = MoveTank(OUTPUT_B, OUTPUT_C)

def movement(left_speed, right_speed, rotations):
tank_pair.on_for_rotations(left_speed, right_speed, rotations, brake=True, block=True)


while not btn.any():
movement(20,20,10)
movement(-100,0,1.5)
movement(20,20,10)
sleep(0.01)

while btn.any():
sleep(0.01)
tank_pair.off()
sound.beep()
exit()
```

Comment: just not use `while btn.any():`

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

you can break your main loop using this

```
pip install keyboard
```

then

```
import keyboard

while True:
    # do something
    if keyboard.is_pressed("q"):
        print("q pressed, ending loop")
        break
```

Comment: I want to do it with the buttons on the EV3 brick.

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is incorrect.

```html
from ev3dev2.motor import MoveTank, OUTPUT_B, OUTPUT_C
from ev3dev2.button import Button
from ev3dev2.sound import Sound
from time import sleep
import time

sound = Sound()
btn = Button()
tank_pair = MoveTank(OUTPUT_B, OUTPUT_C)

def movement(left_speed, right_speed, rotations):
    tank_pair.on_for_rotations(left_speed, right_speed, rotations,       brake=True, block=True)


while not btn.any():
    movement(20,20,10)
    movement(-100,0,1.5)
    movement(20,20,10)
    sleep(0.01)

while btn.any():
    sleep(0.01)
    tank_pair.off()
    sound.beep()
    exit()
```

Comment: I tried that but it just keeps going even if I press the buttons on the brick.

Comment: Yeah, that will happen because you haven't added any keyboard interruptions or anything. It is an infinite loop so it will go on forever. You need to find some sort of library that detects when a button is pressed and apply it in the while loop. I can't help you with that since i do not much knowledge in this field. You will need to do some of your own research

Comment: Idk if this will work because i dont know the module your using, but can't you do something like If btn.any() == 'pressed': exit

Comment: No I want it to stop when I press a button on the EV3 brick. not the keyboard.

Comment: I know how to do it i just don't how to work with that module. Sorry

Comment: could you still show me in the module you do know? That might help.